# Xamarin Forms TableView selected item handler?

Tags: xamarin, tableview, xamarin.forms

I need to trigger a command when user clicks on the table cell.

I looked at [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/) on tablecell, it doesn't talk about any click event handlers.

This is how my XAML looks -

```
<ContentPage Title="Default">
    <TableView>        
        <TableView.Root>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="..." />
                    <Button Text="Home" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Home" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableView.Root>
    </TableView>     
</ContentPage>
```

Right now, command is triggered only when clicked on button, but I want to trigger command when the cell is clicked.

I am new to xamarin, is custom viewcell rendering the only way to achieve this?

If so, any pointers there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Tapped` gesture recognizer within a `ViewCell`.

#### Xaml:

```
<TableView>
    <TableView.Root>
        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell Tapped="OnViewCellTapped">
               ~~~~~
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

#### Code behind:

```
protected void OnViewCellTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tapped");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I add codebehind, it fails with error that method is not found. `An exception of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException' occurred in Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Position 17:23. No method OnViewCellTapped found on type MyApp.Views.AppMasterDetailPage` any thoughts?

Comment: @Yash Enable Xaml compilation so you can find the source of the error during compile time vs. runtime. Something is mismatched between the xaml source and the code behind file... `[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: Thanks, I am using [prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), that's probably why it's different, I will give it a try, but that's a separate issue I think. This should be right answer, I find it disappointing that I don't see `Tapped` in [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TableView/) .

Comment: @Yash Looks like a doc generation issue, as it is a `Cell` type and should be linked back to https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Cell/ which does show OnTapped / Tapped (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Cell.Tapped/)